# VSCode jsonValidation using local schema files

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The documentation for [contributes.jsonValidation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesjsonvalidation) says:

> The url value can be either a local path to a schema file included in the extension or a remote server URL such as a json schema store.

The URL value works as described:

```
"jsonValidation": [{
    "fileMatch": ".jshintrc",
    "url": "http://json.schemastore.org/jshintrc"
}]
```

However, if I create a test extension and give a path to a file that's local to my extension, it does not:

```
"jsonValidation": [{
    "fileMatch": "*.testing",
    "url": "/schemas/testing.schema.json"
}]
```

I have a folder `schemas` at the root of my extension, with a file `testing.schema.json` in it.  It's just a copy of the jshintrc schema.

When I launch my test extension, and load a file that matches the pattern, I get a little green squiggle under the first open brace.  If I hover the green squiggle, I see a familiar error:

> Unable to load schema from '/schemas/edfoo.schema.json': <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
>   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
>   <head> 
>   <title>IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title>

Clearly, it is reaching out to a server, not reading a local file from the extension.  But the docs say I can include a schema file in an extension.  How do I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out: `url` was missing a leading dot, like this:

```
"jsonValidation": [{
    "fileMatch": "*.testing",
    "url": "./schemas/testing.schema.json"
}]
```

When `url` starts with this `./` pattern, it is automatically understood to be a file that shipped with the extension.  If the `./` or even just the `.` is missing off the front, it will be treated as a URL to be fetched from a server instead.

Since vscode is open source, I can reference the line of code that implements this behavior.

It's here:  [jsonMain.ts#L105](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/3f26922adb9f4213eaa56ad6070b2a3529457430/extensions/json/client/src/jsonMain.ts#L105)

Comment: This appears to work while developing/debugging, but once I create and install the vsix extension it no longer appears to work - am I missing something?

Comment: Check to make sure the schema files are getting installed along with the visx.  They should end up someplace like `~/.vscode/extensions/{extensionName}/...`

Comment: Turns out that there was some funky vsix caching during the uninstall/install process, so my "working" code never got installed - all is good now!  thanks for the followup.